# How to change screen in react native with react-navigation on click of a button?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I have defined all my routes/navigations in my root component (App.js) and am trying to access one of those screens (UserScreen) from a child component(LoginScreen) on click of a button.

Here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, TouchableHighlight, Button } from 'react-native';
import LoginComponent from './components/LoginComponent';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


class MainWelcome extends React.Component {
 render() {
   return (
    <View>
     <Text>Welcome Page</Text>
    <Button
      title="Login"
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}
    />
  </View>
  );
 }
}

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
     <LoginComponent />
   </View>
  );
 }
}

class UserScreen extends React.Component {
 render() {
  return (
  <View>
    <Text>Details Screen</Text>
  </View>
  );
 }
}

 const RootStack = StackNavigator(
  {
  Register: {
   screen: RegisterScreen,
  },
  Login: {
   screen: LoginScreen,
  },
  UserPage: {
   screen: UserScreen,
  },
  Welcome: {
   screen: MainWelcome,
  },
 },
{
  initialRouteName: 'Welcome',
 }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <RootStack />
   );
  }
 }
```

This is my LoginComponent.js

```
  import React from 'react';
  import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight, TextInput, StackNavigator } from 'react-native';

  class LoginComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
    super();
        this.state = {
                loginusername: '',
                loginpassword: '',
                isloggedin: false,
                loggedinuser: null,
        }  
      }

  render() {
   return (
    <View>
      <Text>Please Log In</Text>
    <View>
       <TextInput
           placeholder="USERNAME"
           placeholderTextColor = 'black'
           onChangeText={(loginusername) => this.setState({loginusername})}
            />
      <TextInput
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor = 'black'
                onChangeText={(loginpassword) => this.setState({loginpassword})}
            />
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
        {this.props.navigation.navigate('UserPage')}
        }
      }>
      <View>
      <Text>Login</Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>  
  </View>
  );
 }
}

export default LoginComponent;
```

Here in LoginComponent.js, I am doing `{this.props.navigation.navigate('UserPage')}` to redirect to the userscreen on click of a button but it says `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong and if I should be passing something from the App.js to LoginComponent.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you tried to print your LoginComponent's props you would end up with nothing!,
But what if you pass the navigation as prop to your component like this! :

```
// App.js
class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
...
<LoginComponent navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
...
}
```

You will end up with functional navigation prop.

Happy user details navigation :)